# Interpreting the value I receive from the ATDB command for Xbee S2

Tags: xbee, rssi

I realize that this might be the stupidest question that has ever been asked here, but I'm really stuck. I am trying to get the RSSI value of an XBee router so I send ATBD from the coordinator. The value returned is in hexadecimal but I cannot, for the life of me, see how that hexadecimal value interprets as a dBm value.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the command isn't ATBD, but **ATDB**, which means:

"**Received Signal Strength.** This command reports the received signal strength of the last received RF data packet. The DB command only indicates the signal strength of the last hop. It does not provide an accurate quality measurement for a multihop link. DB can be set to 0 to clear it. The DB command value is measured in -dBm. **For example if DB returns 0x50, then the RSSI of the last packet received was -80dBm**. As of 2x6x firmware, the DB command value is also updated when an APS acknowledgment is received." (Retired from XBee ZB User Manual p.131).

As you can see the example above, you just need to:

- Read the Hexadecimal (example: 0x50)
- read it as decimal (example: 0x50 = 80 in decimal)
- multiply by -1: (-1)*80 = **-80 dBm**

The ATBD command is used to change the serial interface data rate (baud rate).